# How is this case class match pattern working?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I've just seen this case class in the Scala `actors` package:

```
case class ! [a](ch: Channel[a], msg: a)
```

And in the JavaDoc it describes usage in the following form:

```
receive {
  case Chan1 ! msg1 => ...
  case Chan2 ! msg2 => ...
}
```

Why is this not:

```
receive {
  case !(Chan1, msg1) => ...
  case !(Chan2, msg2) => ...
}
```

Is the bang operator ! a special case in a similar way to methods ending in a colon :

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When doing pattern matching, the Scala compiler will interpret `o1 c1 o2` the same as `c1(o1, o2)`. That's why `::` works inside pattern matches too.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. A Shame there's not more points to be had from answering Scala questions!