# Scala Get First and Last elements of List using Pattern Matching

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am doing a pattern matching on a list. Is there anyway I can access the first and last element of the list to compare?

I want to do something like..

```
case List(x, _*, y) if(x == y) => true
```

or

`case x :: _* :: y =>`

or something similar... 
where `x` and `y` are first and last elements of the list..

How can I do that.. any Ideas?

Comment: From scala 2.10 you can just use for last def last[T](xs : Seq[T]) = { xs match {
case _ :+ x => x
}}, see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2575

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the standard [:+](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.$colon$plus$) and [+:](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.$plus$colon$) extractors from the `scala.collection` package

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Define a custom extractor object.

```
object :+ {
  def unapply[A](l: List[A]): Option[(List[A], A)] = {
    if(l.isEmpty)
      None
    else 
      Some(l.init, l.last)
  }
}
```

Can be used as:

```
val first :: (l :+ last) = List(3, 89, 11, 29, 90)
println(first + " " + l + " " + last) // prints 3 List(89, 11, 29) 90
```

(For your case: `case x :: (_ :+ y) if(x == y) => true`)

Comment: Neat solution.  What rule/trick in Scala allows `(l :+ last)` to work the same as `(:+(l, last))`?  Didn't realize this was possible.

Comment: Answering my own question -- seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059145/how-is-this-case-class-match-pattern-working/1059161#1059161 with more details here: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-lists.html#16.5

Answer (score 18):

In case you missed the obvious:

```
case list @ (head :: tail) if head == list.last => true
```

The `head::tail` part is there so you don’t match on the empty list.

Comment: Can you please elaborate meaning of ```@``` keyword and its appliance on ```(head :: tail)``` expression? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12):

simply:

```
case head +: _ :+ last =>
```

for example:

```
scala> val items = Seq("ham", "spam", "eggs")
items: Seq[String] = List(ham, spam, eggs)

scala> items match {
     |   case head +: _ :+ last => Some((head, last))
     |   case List(head) => Some((head, head))
     |   case _ => None
     | }
res0: Option[(String, String)] = Some((ham,eggs))
```

Comment: This actually does not work on lists with one element. For that you'd have to add an additional case.

Answer (score 2):

Lets understand the concept related to this question, there is a difference between '::', '+:' and ':+':

**1st Operator**:

'**::**' - It is **right associative operator** which works specially for lists

```
scala> val a :: b :: c = List(1,2,3,4)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

**2nd Operator**:

'**+:**' - It is also **right associative operator** but it works on seq which is more general than just list.

```
scala> val a +: b +: c = List(1,2,3,4)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

**3rd Operator**:

'**:+**' - It is also **left associative operator** but it works on seq which is more general than just list

```
scala> val a :+ b :+ c = List(1,2,3,4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
b: Int = 3
c: Int = 4
```

> The associativity of an operator is determined by the operator’s last character. Operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative. All other operators are left-associative.
>
> A **left-associative** binary operation e1;op;e2 is interpreted as e1.op(e2)
>
> If op is **right-associative**, the same operation is interpreted as { val x=e1; e2.op(x) }, where x is a fresh name.

**Now comes answer for your question**:
So now if you need to get first and last element from the list, please use following code

```
scala> val firstElement +: b :+ lastElement = List(1,2,3,4)
firstElement: Int = 1
b: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
lastElement: Int = 4
```