# Does Scala allow for this kind of extractor?

Tags: scala, unapply

Let's say I have this collection:

```
val a = Array(Array(1,2,3,4,5),Array(4,5),Array(5),Array(1,2,6,7,8))
```

Is there a way to define an extractor which would work in the following way:

```
a.foreach(e => {
   e match {
      case Array( ending with 5 ) => 
      case _ =>
   }
})
```

Sorry for the pseudocode, but I don't know how to express it. Is there a way to match something having 5 as the last element? What if I would want to match something having a 1 as the first element and a 5 as the last? Could this work for arrays of various lengths ( note that I specifically chose different lengths for my arrays in the example ).

Thanks!

Comment: this is very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697645/scala-get-first-and-last-elements-of-list-using-pattern-matching

Comment: Try to avoid deconstructing arrays over extractors, they get looped/copied to Seq with O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a.foreach(e => {
   e match {
      case a: Array[Int] if a.last == 5 => 
      case _ =>
   }
})
```

You can do something a little better for matching on the first elements:

```
a.foreach(e => {
   e match {
      case Array(1, _*) => 
      case _ => 
   }
})
```

Unfortunately the `@_*` thing has to be the last item in the list of array arguments.  But you can make the matching before that as complex as you want.

```
scala> val Array(1, x @_*) = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
x: Seq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val Array(1, b, 3, x @_*) = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
b: Int = 2
x: Seq[Int] = Vector(4, 5)
```

Comment: What's the point of binding `_*` to `x`? Even more so, to `_`?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet: The poster didn't specify whether the array contents were actually needed.  If they're needed, then binding them to a variable allows you to use them.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet: Good call on the `_` though; I didn't realize you could do `_*` by itself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can:

```
object EndsWith {
  def unapply[A]( xs: Array[A] ) = 
    if( xs.nonEmpty ) Some( xs.last ) else None
}
```

On your example:

```
val a = Array(Array(1,2,3,4,5),Array(4,5),Array(5),Array(1,2,6,7,8))

a foreach { 
  case e @ EndsWith(5) => println( e.mkString("(",",",")" ) )
  case _ =>
}
```

It prints as expected `(1,2,3,4,5)`, `(4,5)` and `(5)`

With the same approach, you could write an extractor `StartWith` and then add a method to combine them in a new extractor matching both conditions.

Comment: that's the way extractor did.

Answer (score 4):

The `case` syntax supports `if`s, so this would work:

```
a foreach {
  case a: Array[Int] if a.last == 5 =>
  case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.foreach (ar => ar.last match {                    
  case 5 => println ("-> 5] " + ar.mkString ("~"))
  case _ => println ("   ?] " + ar.mkString (":")) })
```

Why don't you match directly for the last element?

```
-> 5] 1~2~3~4~5
-> 5] 4~5
-> 5] 5
   ?] 1:2:6:7:8
```