# Match order with an extractor

Tags: scala, match, extractor

I defined a custom extractor to get the last element of the list, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697749/1092910:

```
object :+ {
  def unapply[A](l: List[A]): Option[(List[A], A)] = {
    if (l.isEmpty)
      None
    else 
      Some(l.init, l.last)
  }
}
```

Now this matches "good":

```
List(1, 2, 3) match {
  case init :+ last => "good"
  case head :: tail => "bad"
}
```

But if I add another clause, it suddenly matches "bad" now:

```
List(1, 2, 3) match {
  case List(7) => "never"
  case init :+ last => "good"
  case head :: tail => "bad"
}
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: It looks like a bug. I can try asking on one of the mailing list.

Comment: Compile with `scalac -print`, it seems the compiler is doing some optimization with the patterns and merged the test for `List(7)` and `head :: tail`. it first checks if it is a list of Int, then check if first element is 7, if it is not, it falls immediately to `head::tail` and matched `head::tail`. This does seem like a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's #1697/2337 and a dozen duplicates.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1697

It looks safe to say that it will not be fixed in direct fashion, but by deleting the pattern matcher for the virtpatmat implementation.  Try a recent build and compile with -Yvirtpatmat, you'll get the right answer.