# Pattern match against List 'init' and 'last' instead of 'head' and 'tail'

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching, scala-collections

I know that it's possible to easily pattern match against the `head` (or an arbitrary number of initial elements) and `tail` of a `List`:

```scala
val items = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val first :: rest = items

println(first, rest) // 1, List(2, 3, 4)
```

However, I would like to do it the other way - can you use a pattern to get the `init` and `last` of the list?

```scala
val items = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val rest ??? last = items

println(rest, last) // List(1, 2, 3), 4
```

In JavaScript this would look like:

```js
const [...init, last] = items
```

Comment: I think this answer has what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697645/scala-get-first-and-last-elements-of-list-using-pattern-matching/43478668

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:+`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/package$$$colon$plus$.html) custom [**extractor object**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).

So the code would look like this:

```scala
val rest :+ last = items
```

However, note that this is equally inefficient than doing:

```scala
val last :: rest = items.reverse
```

But, if you then need to decompose `rest` again, then `reversing` it first will be more efficient.

Finally, remember both are unsafe since they will throw in case the **List** is empty.

Comment: Cool! Is there documentation on all the builtin extractor objects like this one anywhere? I checked here but I don't see it - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html

Comment: @lan uhm no AFAIK, in any case, there are not too many custom extractors in the stdlib. - What would you like to know?

Comment: I was just wondering what other ones are available.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
val xs :+ x = items
```

Check out: [https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#:+(elem:A):Seq[A]](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#:+(elem:A):Seq%5BA%5D)